# How can i typecast struct returned by malloc to struct type?

Tags: c

How can i typecast address returned by malloc to struct node type?
when i try to compile the following code it shows error every time regarding change in type.

```
struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};
struct node createnode() {
    struct node *n;
    n = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
    // error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct node *' but 'struct node' was expected
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Actually the error is in the return statement. The function's return type is `struct node` while it should've been `struct node *`. Seems like a typo.

Comment: @r3musn0x I actually suspect the error is in the definition of the function, given the use of `malloc()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I meant that the compilation error is in the return statement and not the line the OP commented. The actual error is of course in the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
struct node createnode()
{ ...
```

means your function returns a `struct node`, and **not** a `struct node *`.

```
struct node createnode()
{
struct node *n;
n=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
return(n);
}
```

Note that `n` is a `struct node *` - a *pointer* to a `struct node`.

You left off the `*` in your function definition:

```
struct node *createnode()
{
struct node *n;
n=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
return(n);
}
```

Note that in C you do *not* have to cast a `void` pointer.  In fact, you can hide potential problems if you do.

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 6):

Your `createnode` function returns `struct node` but you return a `struct node*`

You should change the method signature to make it return a `struct node*`

Answer (score 4):

You declared your function as returning a node, but are trying to return a node *.  You probably want to change your function declaration.  `struct node *createnode() ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change `struct node createnode()` to `struct node* createnode()`.

You are trying to return a pointer to `node`, when you are expected to return a `node`.